# EEPROM - writing/reading more than one byte

Tags: c, avr

I've been reading tutorials on EEPROMs and they only deal with one byte at a time. Is there any library that handles reading/writing more than one byte at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the standard libc avr interface in `avr/eeprom.h`, then you can do `eeprom_write_byte`, `eeprom_write_word`, `eeprom_write_dword`, or `eeprom_write_block`. The last one handles arbitrary lengths.

Unless you use external elements, then it depends on how you interface with them. But most likely you're going to send bytes separately anyway. Anything handling larger blocks of memory will only eliminate your call overhead, but continue sending byte by byte.